# ECB xml mapping using jms/serializer-bundle

Tags: php, xml, symfony, guzzle, jmsserializerbundle

How to map xml for jms/serializer so it can read ECB exchange rates xml file and put the currency rate values into `CurrencyRate` object?

I'm trying to get currency rates from ecb website as `CurrencyRate` objects in `$collection` array.

I have this entity:

```
//AppBundle/Entity/CurrencyRates.php
namespace AppBundle\Entity;

class CurrencyRates
{
    private $id;
    private $currency;
    private $rate;
    private $dateCreated;
}
```

And serivce:

```
//AppBundle/Service/CurrencyUpdate.php
use Guzzle\Http\Client;

class CurrencyUpdate
{  
    public function getCurrency()
    {
        $client = new Client('https://www.ecb.europa.eu');
        $request = $client->get('stats/eurofxref/eurofxref-daily.xml?a4103a78edd1c2783f357263fc52faaa');

        $response = $request->send();
        $xml = (string) $response->getBody();

        $serializer = $container->get('jms_serializer'); //I use jms/serializer-bundle and getting by DependencyInjector, this is just for example
        $collection[] = $serializer->deserialize($xml, 'AppBundle\Entity\CurrencyRates', 'xml');
    }
}
```

I need this xml:

```
//this is $xml string from $response->getBody();
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<gesmes:Envelope xmlns:gesmes="http://www.gesmes.org/xml/2002-08-01" xmlns="http://www.ecb.int/vocabulary/2002-08-01/eurofxref">
    <gesmes:subject>Reference rates</gesmes:subject>
<gesmes:Sender>
    <gesmes:name>European Central Bank</gesmes:name>
</gesmes:Sender>
<Cube>
    <Cube time="2017-02-22">
        <Cube currency="USD" rate="1.0513"/>
        ... 
    </Cube>
</Cube>
</gesmes:Envelope>
```

To be mapped for `jms/serializer` in `AppBundle/Resources/config/serializer/Entity.CurrencyRates.xml`.

Something like?(This file is detected by `auto_detection: true` in `config.yml`.):

```
//AppBundle/Resources/config/serializer/Entity.CurrencyRates.xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<serializer>
    <class name="AppBundle\Entity\CurrencyRate" exclusion-policy="all">
        <gesmes:Envelope xmlns:gesmes="http://www.gesmes.org/xml/2002-08-01" xmlns="http://www.ecb.int/vocabulary/2002-08-01/eurofxref">
            <gesmes:subject/>
            <gesmes:Sender>
                <gesmes:name/>
            </gesmes:Sender>
            <Cube>
                <Cube name="dateCreated">
                    <Cube name="currency" value="rate"/>
                </Cube>
            </Cube>
            </gesmes:Envelope>
        </class>
</serializer>
```

Comment: Hello. What is your question? "_'m having trouble understanding_" is not exactly a question that can be answered. Please post some more details regarding your exact question. Visit the help center if you are unsure about the specific guidelines regarding how to ask a good question.